# How can I create a script to fill fields automatically?

Tags: javascript, dom, automation, scripting

I want to create a script with JavaScript that allows me to automatically go to a website and automatically fill in the fields on that website. When all the fields have been filled in automatically, I want the submit button to be clicked and the process to start over. I define the fields by their unique id. I now have the problem that when I run the script that I don't get to the website automatically. Can anyone help me how I could improve my script so that I can automate this process?

Here is my code:

```
function goingToWebsite(){
        window.location.href = 'https://example.com/';
    }

    function fillForm(){
    document.getElementById('gender').value = "Herr"
    document.getElementById('lastname').value = "Example";
    document.getElementById('firstname').value = "Example";
    document.getElementById('address').value = "Example";
    document.getElementById('postcode').value = "Example";
    document.getElementById('city').value = "Example";
    document.getElementById('mobile').value = "Example";
    document.getElementById('email').value = "Example";
    document.getElementById('country_code').value = "Example";
    document.getElementById('birthday').value = "Example";
    document.getElementById('profession').value = "Example";
    document.getElementById('hobbies').value = "Example";
    document.getElementById('skills').value = "Example";
    document.getElementById('wish').value = "Example";
    element = document.getElementById('agb-checkbox');
    element.checked = true;
    }

    function submitForm(){
        document.getElementsByName("JETZT ANMELDEN").click();
    }

    function main(){
        for (let i=0; i<99; i++){
        goingToWebsite();
        fillForm();
        submitForm();
        setTimeout(timeout, 3000);
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot

I have it now like this:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
async function main(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });
    for (let i=0; i<3; i++){
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://beispiel.de/');
    await page.type('#gender', 'Herr');
    await page.type('#lastname', 'Beispiel');
    await page.type('#firstname', 'Beispiel');
    await page.type('#address', 'Beispiel 29');
    await page.type('#postcode', 'Beispiel');
    await page.type('#city', 'Beispiel');
    await page.type('#mobile', '0041797766666');
    await page.type('#email', 'Beispiel@outlook.com');
    await page.type('#country_code', 'Deutschland');
    await page.type('#birthday', '28.07.1995');
    await page.type('#profession', 'Beispiel');
    await page.type('#hobbies', 'Beispiel');
    await page.type('#skills', 'Beispiel');
    await page.type('#wish', 'Beispiel');
    await (await page.waitForSelector('#agb-checkbox')).click();
    const searchBtn = await page.$x("//button[@class='form-btn']");
    searchBtn[0].click();
    await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
    await browser.close();
    }
}
main();
```

When the first loop is finished it doesn't reload again a new page what could be the reason?

Comment: You want us to help you flood a registration form with calls? Because that's what this looks like.

Comment: You can use a password manager - for example LastPass will go to the site and an click will fill in the form with whatever you have set up as information

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with client-side javascript.You should use server-side language for this.After location change, you cannot manage the current site.
If you are familiar with node js you can use [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer).